# Submit worksheet to a web service as a file via POST

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way for a macro tied to a button (i.e. "Upload Sheet To Web Service") embedded in that workbook that will take the current worksheet (either as .xlsx or .csv) or entire workbook and submit it to a web service via POST method?

i.e. `https://www.mywebservice.com/uploads`

A bonus would be to query the user for the username/password or api key but we may be ok with just temporarily hardcoding that.

Comment: VB.Net IsNot vba AndAlso IsNot excel-vba AndAlso VB.Net doesnt do macros

Comment: Ok, I removed that tag. It was showing up as recommended when I constructed the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I've used to post data to a server. The button click handler looped through the active sheet and built some XML to post to the endpoint. This is old code, and I seem to recall that I had to import MSXML2.XMLHTTP before it would work (in the vba editor, go to Tools-References).

```
Sub PostData_ButtonClick()
Dim bldgID As String
Dim year As String
Dim leasid As String

bldgID = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text
year = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Text
Dim Result As String
Result = "<records>"
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("E4:ZZ4").Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
        Result = Result & [redacted]
    End If
Next
Result = Result & "</records>"
DoPost (Result)
End Sub


Function DoPost(xml As String)

Dim xmlDoc As Object
Dim boolValue As Boolean
Dim xmlDocEl As Object
Dim responseText As String
Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim sURL As String

Dim objXML As Object
sURL = "https://www.mywebservice.com/uploads"

Dim sEnv As String

With xmlhtp
    .Open "post", sURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Host", "www.mywebservice.com"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept-encoding", "zip"
    .send "xmlFile=" & xml
    responseText = .responseText
End With
MsgBox "Response from server:" & vbCrLf & responseText
DoPost = responseText
End Function
```

Comment: Hmmm, does this solution with the MSXML2.XMLHTTP require the format  of the content or file to be XML? Is it sending the an XML file as a typical multipart form file attachment or is it sending it as xml content in the payload of the POST? The service we are uploading to 1) is expecting to see a file 2) isn't really expecting an XML formatted content in the file. I wonder if this would work the same if it were a file with CSV formatting instead?

Comment: It doesn't have to be XML. Check this out, it might be more along the lines of what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520212/post-file-to-server-asp-net-using-xmlhttp